# How to deloy fortify ssc.war on apache tomcat9

Tags: tomcat9, fortify, redhat-openjdk, securitycenter

I install jdk1.8 and web apache tomcat9 and star tomcat.service. After log on localhost website apache, I start deloy file ssc.war under /usr/share/tomcat/webapps
Restart and test to failed.

How to deloy fortify ssc.war on apache tomcat9

I try restart and config file ssc.war but no results were obtained

I need help from everyone

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] as well as [help/on-topic]: This question doesn't look like it's programming-related (and if it was, it lacks a [mcve], details to reproduce). Please edit the question to make it on-topic, or find another site in the stackexchange network where it is. On that site: Add more details.